# how to check function name in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-mirrors

I found this answer, but this is not working because this is road syntax.
I want to check if there is a function with the same name as the hash attribute in python.

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Test {
  method1() => "hello";
}

main() {
  print(existsFunction("main")); // true
  print(existsFunction("main1")); // false
  print(existsMethodOnObject(new Test(), "method1")); // true
  print(existsMethodOnObject(new Test(), "method2")); // false
}

bool existsFunction(String functionName) => currentMirrorSystem().isolate
    .rootLibrary.functions.containsKey(functionName);

bool existsMethodOnObject(Object o, String method) => reflect(o).type.methods
    .containsKey(method);
```

Comment: Flutter cannot use `dart:mirrors`.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @jamesdlin The most likely reason anyone would want this is because it's not forbidden, and many programming languages use it very often as well, leading to the surprise of those who encounter such restrictions. The simplest example, Swift and Java allow (and even recommend) the use of reflection. Dart looks strange against their background. In this case, it is not necessarily a fully functional reflection. But at least as much as possible.

Comment: @mezoni That doesn't explain what the OP is ultimately trying to use reflection *for*.  As written, `method1` is statically known to exist on `Test`, and `method2` is statically known not to.  If OP has a `dynamic` type, they alternatively could try to access `method2` and catch a potential `NoSuchMethodError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Test {
  method1() => "hello";
}

main() {
  print(existsFunction("main")); // true
  print(existsFunction("main1")); // false
  print(existsMethodOnObject(Test(), "method1")); // true
  print(existsMethodOnObject(Test(), "method2")); // false
  print(existsMethodOnType<Test>("method1")); // true
  print(existsMethodOnType<Test>("method2")); // false
}

bool existsFunction(String functionName) => currentMirrorSystem()
    .isolate
    .rootLibrary
    .declarations
    .values
    .any((e) => e is MethodMirror && e.simpleName == Symbol(functionName));

bool existsMethodOnObject(Object o, String method) => reflect(o)
    .type
    .declarations
    .values
    .any((e) => e is MethodMirror && e.simpleName == Symbol(method));

bool existsMethodOnType<T>(String method) => reflectClass(T)
    .declarations
    .values
    .any((e) => e is MethodMirror && e.simpleName == Symbol(method));
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
false
true
false
```